# Input box placeholder/label animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I  have a input box with some text written in it like label or placeholder and  on mouse hover I want to change that text and on click want to display a different text which act like a placeholder .

I tried to write css but not able to achieve this,Is their need to write JavaScript to achieve this animation.

Comment: paste your code.

Comment: It is a simple input element want to change its placeholder or label on hover

Answer (score 0):

In Angular? It's easy:

**Component Code Behind**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  placeHolder="";

  onMouseOver() {
    this.placeHolder = "Ein Text"
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.placeHolder = "";
  }
}
```

**And the HTML Part**

```
<input type="text" (mouseover)="onMouseOver()" (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave()" [placeholder]="placeHolder">
```

If the mouse enter the input the placeholder will be visible. Leave it is hidden.

Comment: What is the use of this
name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

Comment: Nothing. Its only the Standard code of Stackblitz example. I have edited my answer.

Comment: But after focusing the input box it still toggles on hovering how to Remove this hover effect on focus

Comment: Remove the `onMouseLeave`handler. Or set a variable if the control is touched/dirty or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of Using input Field using HTML and CSS, You can easily use PrimeNG Float Label which is More Compactible

link : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/floatlabel